# C++ Assignment for Intro Engineering

Tags: c++

**This is the problem my professor wants me to solve with a C++ program...**

> To design a square timber column in a structure, three formulas must
> be satisfied:
>
> column pcture-1.jpg
>
> 1. Buckling load:  The maximum load the column can hold for buckling which needs to be greater than the expected load on the column.
>
> Maximum load = (.3 x E x Area) / (Length / Width)2
>
> 2. Compressive stress: The maximum load the column can hold for compression which needs to be greater than the expected load on the
>    column.
>
> Maximum load = Area x Maximum compressive strength
>
> 3. Slenderness limit:  Ratio of Length to Width of the column must be less than or equal to 50
>
> (Length / Width)<= 50
>
> where: E = the modulus of elasticity = 1,700,000 lb/in2
> Area = width x width = the cross sectional area in square inches
> Maximum compressive strength = 445 lb/in2 for a Douglas Fir tree.
>
> Write a program that uses these three formulas to give an initial
> design to a structural engineer.  Assume the columns to be used are
> square in cross-section and are available in intervals of 2 inches
> (i.e. 2 by 2, 4 by 4, 6 by 6 and so on).  Have the output look like
> the following:
>
> ```
> Please enter the expected load on the column in pounds--> 9000
>
> Please enter the length of the column in inches--> 120
>
>  ... .Testing a beam with Area of 2.0 by 2.0 inches – Failed the tests
>
>  ... .Testing a beam with Area of 4.0 by 4.0 inches – Failed the tests
>
>  ... .Testing a beam with Area of 6.0 by 6.0 inches – Passed the 3 required tests
> ```
>
> For a load of 9000.0 pounds and a length of 120.0 inches, recommended
> square beam has sides of 6.0 inches   The timber cost will be $ 216
>
> You must write a function for each of the three tests using call by
> value.  Your main program will call these three functions in order to
> solve the problem.   Test your program for the above input and for the
> case of 18000 lb load and column length 72 inches.  If the price of
> the timber is  0.05 $/in3 report the difference between the cost of
> the timbers.

**This is the program I wrote, but it forms an endless loop; I am not sure how to fix it, and solve the problem my professor wants me to.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> // outfile
#include <cmath>

#define E 1700000 // lb/in^3 (E is modulus of elasticity)
#define MCS 445 // lb/in^3 (MCS is maximum compressive strength)

using namespace std;

bool buckling_load();
bool compressive_stress();
bool slenderness_limit();

//1.0 declare variables
float expected_load;
float column_length;
bool tests_passed = false;
float column_width = 2;

int main() {
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("outfile.txt");

    //2.0 get user input
    cout << "Please enter the expected load on the column (lbs), and the 
    column length (in) ->" << endl;
    cin >> expected_load >> column_length;

    //3.0 test the different widths
    while (!tests_passed) {
        if (buckling_load() && compressive_stress() &&  slenderness_limit()){
            tests_passed = true;
            cout << column_width << " by "<< column_width << " Passed the  three required tests";
        }
        else {
            cout << column_width << " by "<< column_width << " Failed the  three required tests";
            column_width +=2;
        }
    }
}

//4.0 define functions
bool buckling_load(){
    if (expected_load < ((0.3 * E * pow(column_width, 2)) / pow(column_length / column_width, 2))){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

bool compressive_stress(){
    if (expected_load < ((pow(column_width,2)) * MCS)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

bool slenderness_limit(){
    if(50 <= (column_length/column_width)){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, one line at a time, what did you see?

Comment: the program compiled fine... it didn't flag any bugs

Comment: "Compiling" (without error) is simply the first step.  Sam Varsavchick is absolutely correct: learning your debugger is every bit as essential a skill as getting a clean compile.  Step through your code to determine why `tests_passed` is never being set to "true".

Comment: No compiler ever "flags any bugs". This is not what a compiler does. This is what humans do, with a debugger. This is what a debugger does: run a program, one line at a time, and on each step you can see what all the variables' values are, and inspect the current state of the program, and determine why it does what it does, or does not do. Learning how to effectively use a debugger is a mandatory skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions.

Comment: Compilers can only flag potential sources of bugs. Important to pay enable and pay attention to warnings.

Comment: Put another way, "It compiles" does **not** mean "It does what I want it to do".

Comment: See @Eugene's answer. Your `50 <= (column_length/column_width)` only trends further `false` as `column_width +=2;` increases. You can also remove `endl` after `"... column length (in) -> ";` and add `'\n'` after each `"...required tests\n"`

Comment: @IzabellaDyer -- The compiler has no idea what the program is supposed to do -- it only follows the orders you give it.  All it cares about is if the syntax of the code is correct.  For example, if I asked you to create a program to add two numbers, but instead you (by mistake because of a bug in your code) created a program that subtracted two numbers, the code will compile with no errors.  But is the program correct?  No.  It was supposed to add two numbers, not subtract them.  The compiler cannot read your mind as to what you really wanted to do -- only you know that.

Answer (score 2):

This condition

> Slenderness limit: Ratio of Length to Width of the column must be less
> than or equal to 50

does not correspond to your source:

```
bool slenderness_limit(){
    if(50 <= (column_length/column_width)){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The condition should be reversed:

```
if(50 >= (column_length/column_width))
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would suggest advising against this pattern: `if (cond) { return true; } else { return false; }`. As all branches `return` it's much clearer to write `return cond;` or in this case: `bool slenderness_limit() { return 50 <= (column_length / column_width); }`.  This issue is present several times in the OP's code.

Comment: @Chris I entirely agree with you, but I wanted to show OP their bug rather than teach them good style.